# Another jquery :not selector question

Tags: jquery, selector

The :not always gives me such headache.  I am trying to not repeat an addition of plus sign. This is the selector that gives me the element I want:

```
#submenu li.current_page_ancestor.current_page_parent a:first
```

**Basically I want to say that if that selector does NOT already have a plus in front of it, add it**. But where do i put the :not and the various contains? I've tried this, which didn't work:

```
$j('#submenu li.current_page_ancestor.current_page_parent a:first:not('contains("+")')).prepend("+ ");
```

thanks so much! (also, if anyone can recommend a way to not use :not, and use ! instead, that would be spectacular!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try 
`$j('#submenu li.current_page_ancestor.current_page_parent a:first:not(contains("+"))').prepend("+ ");`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var el = $j('#submenu li.current_page_ancestor.current_page_parent a:first');
if( el.text().match( /^\+/ ) ) { el.prepend( '+' ); }
```